# the given input string was not in a correct format in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i'm trying to read the text box fields values and checking if they are null assigning the zero integer value.

then i'm assigning the every`textbox.text` to integer values. but here it is showing error as Input string was not in a correct format. how to overcome this

```
 if (txtYearofPurchased.Text == null || 
     txtMonthofPurchased.Text == null || 
     txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text == null || 
     txtCurrentYearEnd.Text == null|| 
     txtCost.Text == null || 
     txtDepnRate1.Text ==null)
    {
        txtYearofPurchased.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
        txtMonthofPurchased.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
        txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text= Convert.ToString(0);
        txtCost.Text= Convert.ToString(0);
        txtDepnRate1.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
    }

    int yearofpurchase = Int32.Parse(txtYearofPurchased.Text);
    int monthofpurchase = Int32.Parse(txtMonthofPurchased.Text);
    int CurrentMonth = Int32.Parse(txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text);// present month
    int CurrentYearend = Int32.Parse(txtCurrentYearEnd.Text);// present year
    float Cost = Int32.Parse(txtCost.Text);
    float DepnRate1 = Int32.Parse(txtDepnRate1.Text) / 100;
    float ad = AD();
```

Comment: What *is* the text value that caused the problem? You can't parse non-integer values and that's what the error message is saying. If you want to avoid such errors, add input validation in your form

Comment: The `TextBox.Text` property is usually never `null`, but mostly an empty string. So probably your `if` block simply does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. you are not using the else-block of the `if`, so you are using `int.Parse` even if they are already detected as invalid.
2. Use `int.TryParse` instead of null-check+`int.Parse` since the `Text` property is never null, it returns `String.Empty` instead. And you also have to handle invalid input.

So like this:

```
int yearofpurchase,monthofpurchase,CurrentMonth,CurrentYearend;
float Cost,DepnRate1,ad;
bool validYearOfPurchase = int.TryParse(txtYearofPurchased.Text, out yearofpurchase);
bool validMonthOfPurchase = int.TryParse(txtMonthofPurchased.Text, out monthofpurchase);
bool validCurrentMonth = int.TryParse(txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text, out CurrentMonth);
bool validCurrentYearend= int.TryParse(txtCurrentYearEnd.Text, out CurrentYearend);
if(!validYearOfPurchase || !validMonthOfPurchas || !validCurrentMonth || !validCurrentYearend)
{
    txtYearofPurchased.Text = "0";
    txtMonthofPurchased.Text = "0";
    txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text = "0";
    txtCurrentYearEnd.Text = "0";
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int yearofpurchase;
    int monthofpurchase;
    int CurrentMonth;
    int CurrentYearend;
    float Cost;
    float DiffinAccumdepnatbeggining;
    float DepnRate1;
    bool res = int.TryParse(txtYearofPurchased.Text, out yearofpurchase);
    bool MOP = int.TryParse(txtMonthofPurchased.Text, out monthofpurchase);
    bool CM = int.TryParse(txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text, out CurrentMonth);// present month
    bool CYE = int.TryParse(txtCurrentYearEnd.Text, out CurrentYearend);// present year
    bool cost = float.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out Cost);
    bool DCB = float.TryParse(txtDiffinAccumdepnatbeggining.Text, out DiffinAccumdepnatbeggining);
    bool DR = float.TryParse(txtDepnRate1.Text, out DepnRate1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `TextBox.Text` can not be `null`, but an empty string. Also `Convert.ToString(0)` is `"0"`, so I would change your code like this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtYearofPurchased.Text) || 
    String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtMonthofPurchased.Text) || 
    String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text) || 
    String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtCurrentYearEnd.Text) || 
    String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtCost.Text) || 
    String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtDepnRate1.Text))
{
    txtYearofPurchased.Text = "0";
    txtMonthofPurchased.Text = "0";
    txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text= "0";
    txtCost.Text= "0";
    txtDepnRate1.Text = "0";
}

int yearofpurchase = Int32.Parse(txtYearofPurchased.Text);
int monthofpurchase = Int32.Parse(txtMonthofPurchased.Text);
int CurrentMonth = Int32.Parse(txtCurrentMonthEnd.Text);// present month
int CurrentYearend = Int32.Parse(txtCurrentYearEnd.Text);// present year
float Cost = Int32.Parse(txtCost.Text);
float DepnRate1 = Int32.Parse(txtDepnRate1.Text) / 100;
```